# Type mismatch in Scala's for-comprehension

Tags: scala

I have tried to define a recursive Scala function that looks something like this:

```
  def doSomething: (List[List[(Int, Int)]], List[(Int, Int)], Int, Int) => List[Int] =
  (als, rs, d, n) =>
    if (n == 0) {
      for (entry <- rs if (entry._1 == d)) yield entry._2
    } else {
      for (entry <- rs; adj <- als(entry._1)) yield doSomething(als, rs.::((adj._1, adj._2 + entry._2)), d, n - 1)
    }
```

Now, the compiler tells me:

> `|      |      |      |      |      | <console>:17: error: type mismatch;
>        found   : List[List[Int]]
>        required: List[Int]
>                for (entry <- rs; adj <- als(entry._1)) yield doSomething(als, rs.::((adj._1, adj._2 + entry._2)), d, n - 1)
>                           ^`

I cannot figure out what the problem is. I'm sure that I'm using `<-` correctly. On the other hand, I'm a Scala newbie coming from the Java world...

Regarding the types of the input:

`als` : `List[List[(Int,Int)]]`,

`rs` : `List[(Int,Int)]`,

`d` and `n` : `Int`

The compiler error appears as soon as I tell IntelliJ to send my code to the Scala console.

Comment: Isn't that given by the method declaration?
`(List[List[(Int, Int)]], List[(Int, Int)], Int, Int)`

Comment: Is it? What is `List[Int]` then? I always thought that the things on the left-hand side of the `=>` are the input parameters...

Comment: @DmitriiC. is right. `als` is a `List[List[(Int, Int)]]`, `rs` is a `List[(Int, Int)]`, `d` and `n` are `Int`s.

Comment: the problem is that you have nested for loop in else expression which is generating List[List[Int]].

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: Some following the `[scala]` tag here on StackOverflow have noticed several of these questions, with recurring patterns in how the code is laid out (e.g.: declaring a function - and not a method - with a `def` and using `List`s a lot). Out of curiosity, do you mind if I ask whether there is a common source?

Comment: To be honest, I'm learning Scala in a university course. This is how we're taught to do it...

Comment: Totally fine, it's just that apparently many of your fellow students have used StackOverflow in the last few days and noticing the pattern caused the curiosity. ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah, probably :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `yield` an `A` when iterating on a `List`, you return a `List[A]`. `doSomething` returns a `List[Int]`, so by yielding that you return a `List[List[Int]]`. You can unroll that like this:

```
def doSomethingElse(als: List[List[(Int, Int)]], rs: List[(Int, Int)], d: Int, n: Int): List[Int] =
  if (n == 0) {
    for ((k, v) <- rs if k == d) yield v
  } else {
    for {
      (k, v) <- rs
      (adjk, adjv) <- als(k)
      item <- doSomethingElse(als, (adjk, adjv + v) :: rs, d, n - 1)
    } yield item
  }
```

Notice that I also used a method notation for brevity and destructured the pairs and leveraged the right-associativity of methods whose name ends in `:` for readability, feel free to use whatever convention you might want (but I don't see really a reading why having a method that returns a constant function (maybe you'd want to just use a `val` to declare it).

As a further note, you are using random access on a linear sequence (`als(k)`), you may want to consider an indexed sequence (like a `Vector`). More info on the complexity characteristics of the Scala Collection API can be found [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Answer (score 2):

for test purpose I created some sample data that meets the input datatypes as

```
val als = List(List((1,2), (3,4)), List((1,2), (3,4)), List((1,2), (3,4)))
//als: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,2), (3,4)), List((1,2), (3,4)), List((1,2), (3,4)))
val rs = List((1,2), (2,3))
//rs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3))
val d = 1
//d: Int = 1
val n = 3
//n: Int = 3
```

And in you doSomething function when `n == 0` you are doing

```
for (entry <- rs if (entry._1 == d)) yield entry._2
//res0: List[Int] = List(2)
```

You can see that the return type is `List[Int]`

And for the else part you are calling recursively doSomething.

I have created dummy `doSomething` method of yours as **your doSomething function definition lacks input variables** as

```
 def dosomething(nn: Int)={
  for (entry <- rs if (entry._1 == d)) yield entry._2
}
```

and I call the method recursively as

```
for (entry <- rs; adj <- als(entry._1)) yield dosomething(0)
//res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2), List(2), List(2), List(2))
```

Clearly you can see that the second nested for loop is returning `List[List[Int]]`

And thats what the compiler is warning you

> `error: type mismatch;
>        found   : List[List[Int]]
>        required: List[Int]`

I hope the answer is helpful